# How can I Handle strong types over Redis Hashes?

Tags: c#, redis, json.net, stackexchange.redis

My client sends the server a json (*JObject*) and I have a custom method that flattens the value into a key value pair.

Assuming this is my json

```
{
   Prop1: 12,
   Prop2: "Str",
   Prop3:{
      Prop4: 222.4
   }
}
```

A Dictionary of flattened data is created that looks like this:

```
"Prop1": 12
"Prop2": "Str"
"Prop3.Prop4": 222.4
```

Now, I'm using *Redis* (the *StackExchange.Redis* client) for holding this data.

I generate a key (e.g. obj:123456) and add the dictionary's key values as hash entries.

The data gets saved on *Redis*, but my problem is that I need to distinguish between types when I retrieve the data from *Redis*.

I noticed the `IsInteger` flag and wanted to try using it as a begining.
I've created a `HashEntry` with an integer value (`IsInteger` was true) and then `HashSetted` the data.
When I fetched the data using `HashGet`, I've noticed that IsInteger flag was false.

Is there any reason that the `IsInteger` flag gets lost between `HashSet` and `HashGet`?

Is there any trivial way to handle types (string\int\double\date) over *Redis*? I can think of a custom implementation, but I'd want to go there.

**Edit - Here's a code example:**

```
Dictionary<string, object> objs = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"Prop1", 12},
    {"Prop2", "Str"},
    {"Prop3.Prop4", 222.4},
};

var redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationOptions.Parse("localhost:6379,name=SafeRedisConnection,connectTimeout=100000,syncTimeout=100000,abortConnect=false,defaultDatabase=5"));

// just a test
var hashEntries = objs.Where(kvp => kvp.Value is int).Select(kvp => new HashEntry(kvp.Key, (int)kvp.Value));
var hashEntries1 = objs.Where(kvp => kvp.Value is string).Select(kvp => new HashEntry(kvp.Key, (string)kvp.Value));
var hashEntries2 = objs.Where(kvp => kvp.Value is double).Select(kvp => new HashEntry(kvp.Key, (double)kvp.Value));

var arr = hashEntries.Union(hashEntries1).Union(hashEntries2).ToArray();
redisConnection.GetDatabase().HashSet("obj:123456", arr);

var keys = redisConnection.GetDatabase().HashKeys("obj:123456");
var dic = keys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => redisConnection.GetDatabase().HashGet("obj:123456", k));
```

Comment: Could you add the code as to how you set the data and get the data?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I've added some code. The separation by type is just something that I've tested for the IsInteger thing. I'd be glad to here about better practices of obtaining "types" over Redis.

Comment: Here is a library that provides such functionality:
https://github.com/elglogins/STRHM

Comment: @Edward Thanks. I've ended up doing something similar with a custom serializer

Answer (score 1):

You should play with your own Redis key naming conventions. And remember that, in Redis, all simple values are *strings* (well, byte arrays... but *StackExchange.Redis* has an implicit operator to turn a `RedisValue` into `string`).

For example, when you add a *pair* on some Redis hash, the key could be `<propertyName>:<type>` and this way you can work on converting key values into CLR types again...

Another approach could be both storing that hashes along with another hash for each one to store keys' data types:

```
var hashEntries = objs.Where(kvp => kvp.Value is int)
                      .Select
                      (
                          kvp => new HashEntry
                          (
                              kvp.Key, 
                              kvp.Value.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName
                          )
                      );
```

Whenever you get some or all hash entries, you can get also its *just metadata* counterpart to check each value type.

BTW, I believe that you should really consider injecting JSON-serialized objects into a global/partitioned hash, or using simple key-string keys as part of the global keyspace and you'll avoid these problems.

I would use hashes to store individual properties if I need to perform some operations like indexing data by some property or other cases... but if you're just storing full objects, consider my purposed approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about some custom implementations (like that one you suggested \ a byte array implementation with the first byte as the "type") - But that will kill my implementation's performance. I'm using the flattening technique for a reason and I was hoping for something more robust. +1 for the effort.

Comment: @AmirPopovich But the first byte thing is an overkill, you can use a key naming scheme! :D